# Select last different rows mysql

Tags: mysql

how can select last different rows?

VIDEOS

```
idvideo name                       
1684    Uno spettacolo da rimanerci
1301    Ciao
1684    Ciamooooo
1823    Prova
1333    Prova2
```

VIDEOS_VIEWS

```
idvideo dateview
1684    09-01-2014 11.30
1684    09-01-2014 11.31
1823    09-01-2014 11.31
1684    09-01-2014 11.32
1333    09-01-2014 11.33
1684    09-01-2014 11.34
1333    09-01-2014 11.35
```

I want this result:

```
idvideo dateview          name
1333    09-01-2014 11.35  Prova2
1684    09-01-2014 11.34  Ciamooooo
1823    09-01-2014 11.31  Prova
```

This is the query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM videos_views  
INNER JOIN videos  
    ON videos_views.idvideo = videos.idvideo 
GROUP BY videos_views.idvideo
ORDER BY MAX(videos_views.dateview)
DESC LIMIT 3
```

but is too low

Comment: What is your current query?

Comment: SELECT * FROM videos_views INNER JOIN videos ON videos_views.idvideo = videos.idvideo WHERE visibile = '1' GROUP BY videos_views.idvideo ORDER BY MAX(videos_views.datavisualizzazione) DESC LIMIT 3

Answer (score 0):

```
select VIDEOS_VIEWS.*,VIDEOS.name from VIDEOS LEFT JOIN VIDEOS  ON VIDEOS_VIEWS.idvideo  = VIDEOS.idvideo group by VIDEOS.idvideos DESC limit 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use DISTINCT for this

```
SELECT DISTINCT vv.idvideo, vv.dateview, v.name FROM videos_views as vv INNER JOIN videos as v ON vv.idvideo = v.idvideo WHERE visibile = '1' GROUP BY vv.idvideo ORDER BY MAX(vv.datavisualizzazione) DESC LIMIT 3
```